# Linking SWF and html

Tags: jquery, actionscript-3, flash, xhtml, externalinterface

Is something like this possible:

I have a flash animation of a glowing orb.
Orb should always be dark, but should glow when i hover over menu items.

SWF file is written using actionscript3.

And menu looks something like this

```
<ul class ="menu">
    <li class="menuitem">menu1</li>
    <li class="menuitem">menu2</li>
    <li class="menuitem">menu3</li>
    <li class="menuitem">menu4</li>
</ul>
```

I want my orb to glow whenever i hover over menuitem class. Should I link with jQ or should I create another SWF file for the menu and then link them together (if so, how do I do that).

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Investigate [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) API and trigger Actionscript functions back from Javascript so every time you hover, trigger the necessary function in Flash to enable the glowing effect.